#  How Can I Capture an Event When I Login / Logout from Facebook Comment Box?

Tags: facebook, events, refresh

Is there any way to capture a Facebook event when I login or logout from any Facebook social plugin, like comment box or like button? I want to refresh my page whenever a user logins into a Facebook plugin. Because when I login with comment box it doesn't show that I am logged in and so I can't use the "Like" button. But when I refresh my page it shows I am logged in to both plugins.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'My App ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: false });

        setTimeout(aaa, 6000);

        FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function (targetUrl) {
            $("#myh1").html("Facebook Loaded");
            alert('edge.create');
        });


        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());

    function aaa() {
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fbDiv'), function () {
            alert('I rendered');
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="fbDiv">
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/AiLiveCaptions" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i see it, this could be the default behaviour when you are using two separate plugins weather they are of facebook or any third party website i.e.facepile/commentbox.

your browser needs to reload in order to update the session on page across multiple plugins on same page, just like the difference when you are open any mail id across multiple tabs with opening same id on different browsers.